# Azure Automation | Runbook | Powershell | Get-AzRoleAssignment | Microsoft.Rest.Azure.CloudException

Tags: powershell, azure-automation, service-principal

I have an Automation account and I have set up the Run-As-Account for non-classic resources. In my automation Account I have imported Az.Resources, Az.Account, Az.Storage and Az.KeyVault.

I have a script that does not work under the Automation service principle. The following error is a first of 3;

> Get-AzRoleAssignment : Exception of type 'Microsoft.Rest.Azure.CloudException' was thrown. At line:26 char:10

I have granted the application registration the following set of **application api permissions** in Azure Active Directory (more than I anticipate needing);

[image]

At the start of the script I run the Connect-AzAccount cmdlet;

```
 $servicePrincipalConnection = Get-AutomationConnection -Name 'AzureRunAsConnection'
Connect-AzAccount -ServicePrincipal `
    -Tenant $servicePrincipalConnection.TenantID `
    -ApplicationId $servicePrincipalConnection.ApplicationID `
    -CertificateThumbprint $servicePrincipalConnection.CertificateThumbprint
```

Followed by the failing command;

```
    If(!(Get-AzRoleAssignment | Where-Object { $_.RoleDefinitionName -eq "Storage Blob Data Contributor" `
    -and $_.scope -eq "/subscriptions/$subscription/resourceGroups/$resourceGroup/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/$serviceName" `
    -and $_.SignInName -eq (Get-AzContext).Account.Id})){
    # There does not exist the requisite permission for the run-as-account context, grant; 'Storage Blob Data Contributor'.
    New-AzRoleAssignment -RoleDefinitionName "Storage Blob Data Contributor" `
        -ApplicationId (Get-AzADServicePrincipal | Where-Object { $_.DisplayName -eq "jupiterautomation01" }).ApplicationId `
        -Scope "/subscriptions/$subscription/resourceGroups/$resourceGroup/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/$serviceName"
}
```

I need to grant the right permissions, but do not know what they are.

Comment: Could you please tell me if you have done admin consent?

Comment: Seems like the same error 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55566553/exception-of-type-microsoft-rest-azure-cloudexception-was-thrown

Comment: Are you referring to the permission blade of the application in Active Directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The permissions assigned need to be consented to by an 'admin'. The button was only available when accessing Azure via the Microsoft account used to create the Active Directory tenant.

1. Sign in with an admin account that can consent.
2. Grant API permissions to read or read/write (i needed write as well) on Active Directory to the application.
3. Give admin consent using the button displayed in the image.

[image]